# Custom validation not firing when expected

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate

I'm using validation on an MVC view. I'm using some data annotations on other properties of my model (like Required and Length) but I needed to write a custom validator like the following to compare dates.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $.validator.addMethod("enddate", function(value, element) {
         var startdatevalue = $('.startdate').val();
         return Date.parse(startdatevalue) < Date.parse(value);
  }, "End Date should be greater than Start Date.");

});
```

I'm adding the "enddate" class to the textbox so it validates. However, the validation doesn't fire when expected. In my scenario it should fire when clicking the submit button like the rest of the other validators, however, the custom validator fires when I lose focus from the textbox. Is there any way I can make the custom validator fire when the rest of the other validations happen. Additionally, the error isn't being reported in the validation summary but the validator fires and changes the color of the textbox to red.

Comment: You could call $(form).valid() or $(form).validate() when submitting the form.

Comment: I think there is some confusion. I stated the rest of the validators are ALREADY firing upon clicking submit button. THAT is how I want this custom validator to behave. However, it is not, it's firing on losing focus from the textbox. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.validator.addMethod("enddate", function(value, element) {
   var startdatevalue = $('.startdate').val();
   return Date.parse(startdatevalue) < Date.parse(value);
  }, "End Date should be greater than Start Date.");
$('#yourformid').validate();
});
```

I think it works.

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue. Please see my comment above. Thanks for taking the time to post.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.validator.addMethod("endDate", function (value, element) {
            var startDate = $('.startDate').val();
            return Date.parse(startDate) <= Date.parse(value);
        }, "* End date must be Equal/After start date");
    });
```

its working code , i am using it

Answer (score 0):

You could call $(form).valid() or $(form).validate() when the button is clicked.

```
$("submitbutton").click(function(){

if(!$(form).valid())
{
  return false;
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

review the below article:

http://nickstips.wordpress.com/2011/11/05/asp-net-mvc-lessthan-and-greaterthan-validation-attributes/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+NickOlsensProgrammingTips+%28Nick+Olsen%27s+Programming+Tips%29

Something used there like:

```
function appendModelPrefix(value, prefix) {
    if (value.indexOf('*.') === 0) {
        value = value.replace('*.', prefix);
    }
    return value;
}
```

This might be the problem if your models is under another class. For example: `MyViewModel.Person` if so, the name of the elements will be like: `Person.Name`.